# Android HttpUrlConnection Response wait time

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I have below code. I am getting HTTP response code -1. Just to troubleshoot, I would like to know if I should wait after making connection for a while before checking the http response code.

```
String requestURL = "https://www.google.com";

HttpURLConnection connection = new HttpURLConnection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(this.connection.getOutputStream());
       writer.write(getHttpData());
writer.flush();
writer.close();

if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  inputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
}
```

Is getResponseCode() or getInputStream() blocking call ? Am I reading response too soon ? Should I wait ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason you could be getting the weird HTTP response code of `-1` is the connection-pooling with-http-keep-alives *bug* that's in Android platform versions up to (and including) Froyo, ie Android v2.2.

The [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) gives the following code snippet to resolve the problem (note that they say it doesn't include Froyo, although we found that it did - the snippet below is modified accordingly):

```
private void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
    // HTTP connection reuse which was buggy pre-froyo
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) <= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}
```

Try calling that when your app starts-up and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @Marek It looks like the code you changed was incorrect. The point of the answer was that Roberto had to change the `<` to `<=`